# I am reading "The C Programming Language" (2ed) and I didn't understand a concept:

Tags: arrays, c, integer

I am reading "The C programming Language" (2ed) and I didn't understand a concept.

There is this code to copy input to output

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int c;
    c = getchar();
    while (c != EOF) {
        putchar(c);
        c = getchar();
    }
}
```

In the beginning, `c` is declared as an `int` type variable, but if I write something like "test line" the output is the expected "test line". My question is: how is `c` declared as an `int` type variable but the program stores space enough to store a lot of characters? "Inside" the computer, it registers as an array of characters? How does this process work?

Comment: `c` represents a single character.

Comment: You might be interested in [these course notes](https://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/krnotes/sx4f.html) written to accompany the chapter you're reading.

Comment: The program does not store all those characters, just one at a time, which it outputs and then forgets.

Comment: You don't have any arrays in this program: not an array of `char`, *or* an array of `int`.  That's because there's no need to store a whole set of characters (a word, or a line, or the whole file) all at once at all.  This code operates on characters one at a time: input one, output one, repeat.

Comment: i think i understand now. The code does not store all at one place. It repeats the process for every character, stores in these buffers from the stdin, and then it shows to the user. Thanks for the explenation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but if i write something like "test line" the output is the expected "test line".

> how is "c" declared as a `int` type variabel but the program stores space enough to a lot of characters ?

All that input is not stored in variable `c` at the same time, but in input and output buffers.  Variable `c` handles those characters one at a time.

Lets walk though the sequence of events.

1. `main()` starts and runs to `getchar()`.
2. `getchar()` waits for input.
3. User types `t`, the OS buffers the character.
4. User types `e` `s` ...., `e` the OS buffers those characters.
5. User types <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the OS buffers the character `'\n'` and gives the buffer to `stdin` for `getchar()` to start using.
6. `getchar()` returns `t` and saves in `c`.
7. Code continues to `putchar(c);` and puts the `t` in the `stdout` buffer.
8. Code continues to `getchar();`, returns the buffered `e` and saves in `c`.
9. Code continues to `putchar(c);` and puts the `e` in the `stdout` buffer.
10. 8 - 9 repeat for `st line`.
11. Code continues to `getchar();`, returns the buffered `\n` and saves in `c`.
12. Code continues to `putchar(c);` and puts the `\n` in the `stdout` buffer.  The buffer is now flushed to the OS output terminal.  Output now visible.
13. Back to step 2 until no input available.

Comment: Thanks ! I did not know  about the buffers in the OS. Now it makes much more sense!

Answer (score 2):

First, some background.

A character is an element of a string. A character is a *number*.

The glyphs you see on the screen (`a`, `b`, etc) are simply how your terminal interprets the numbers it receives (97, 98, etc).

In a C program, there is absolutely no difference between

```c
'a'
```

```c
97
```

Both are integer literals of type `int` with a value of ninety-seven. (I'm assuming ASCII-based machines here. They're actually different on an EBCDIC-based machine.)

---

Now for your question.

> but the program stores space enough to a lot of characters ?

It does not. `c` only contains a single character at any given time. The first time through the loop, 116 aka 't' is assigned to it. The second time through the loop, 101 aka 'e' is assigned to it. etc.

Comment: Minor: "Both are integer literals of type int" --> C calls them _constants_.  C has 2 _literals_: _string_ and _compound_.

Comment: @chux - Reinstate Monica, I don't mean constant. You can assign a constant to a variable, but you can't assign a literal to a variable. A constant is a value, but a literal is a piece of code. Sure, they produces constants, but that's besides the point.

Answer (score 1):

> how is "c" declared as a int type variabel but the program stores space enough to a lot of characters ?

The source code shown does not store a lot of characters. It processes one character at a time.

`c = getchar();` puts the code for one input character in `c`. Then `putchar(c);` writes that code to output. Then the program can forget about the character. It does not need it any more, and it can get a new character code and reuse `c` for that.

The output stream may hold a lot of characters in a buffer before writing them to the output device, but that is in separate source code that is not directly in the source code shown. It is part of the C standard libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose I'm mixing drinks for my friends.  I have four glasses in front of me.  I want to put 1/8 cup (1 shot) of gin in each glass.  But I don't have a 1/8 cup measuring cup.  So I get a 1/4 cup measuring cup, and I fill it halfway, and that way I measure 1/8 cup of liquor for each glass.

Is it a problem that I used a 1/4 cup measure to measure 1/8 cup of liquid?  What about all the empty space at the top?  Well, obviously, it won't cause any problem at all.

Similarly, if you use an `int` (which is probably a 16- or 32-bit variable) to hold the return value from calling `getchar()`, this won't cause any problem at all even if most of the character values that come back from `getchar` are just 8 bits.

But it *will* make a difference when it comes time for `getchar` to return the code `EOF` (end of file) to you!  `EOF` is a value that will *not* fit in 8 bits, because it is (by definition) not an 8-bit character value.  That's why it's important to use an `int` variable to handle values coming back from `getchar`, not `char` as might seem   obvious.

Comment: I don't think this was the question, but how the whole input "test line" was held in a single variable.

Comment: @WeatherVane Maybe not, but I'm hoping it will provide some insight.

Answer (score -1):

- something is called io buf,other called return value
- Specifically, it can be understood as getchar read chars to io buffer, and return one by one to api user