# Why putchar() and getchar() are accepting more than one character when using while loop..?

Tags: c, while-loop, getchar, putchar

Here, I have understood why *putchar()* is printing only the first character that is 'C'

```
#include <stdio.h>
main(){
    int c;
    c = getchar();
    putchar(c);
}

output : > Cprograming
         > C
```

But, When using a *while loop* the behavior of those functions is changing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
main(){
    int c;
    c = getchar();
    while(c != 2){
        putchar(c);
        c = getchar();
    }
}

output : > Cprograming
         > Cprograming
         > Bells and Wistles
         > Bells and Wistles
         ...
```

Why suddenly *getchar()* and *putchar()* are storing and printing more than one character..??
Why is this happening..??

I tried to practice it this way.

```
int c,d,e,f,g;
    c = getchar();
    putchar(c);
    d = getchar();
    putchar(d);
    e = getchar();
    putchar(e);
    f = getchar();
    putchar(f);
    g = getchar();
    putchar(g);
```

This is my assumption how program might be working.

> Start with c = getchar()

> User enter 'Qwerty'

> getchar() stores this 'Qwerty' one by one character in something called
> input buffer(sorry for technical words)

> user hits enter, getchar() returns the first character from buffer
> and store it into c

> putchar(c), sends this value to something called output buffer,
> Now output buffer has Q stored in it
> .
> Next, d = getchar(), now this new getchar(), goes to the input buffer
> asks for the top character stored in it and return it to 'd'

> putchar(d), sends this new d value to output buffer, and now output
> buffer contains 'Qw'

--this repeats until we don't have enough getchar() & putchar() or we run out of characters.

> In this case, we don't have enough getchar() & putchar(). So, the output
> screen will look something like this

```
Qwerty
Qwert
```

My question is,

Why d = getchar(); collects character from buffer.
Why it does not just start a new stream for itself...?

I mean  c = getchar(); says ok start typing
and

d = getchar(); No, don't start typing. first check if buffer has something left. if it doesn't only then start typing.

Why..?

I'm really sorry if I'm being absolutely silly. Just a beginner programmer. Hope you guys
understand.

Comment: Because in the first program you read one char and you print one char and in the second program you read and print chars until you press Ctrl+B.

Comment: How are you able to move 100 bricks from one side to the other while you can only carry 1 brick at a time? The solution is the same as with your question. You do it one by one until you are done. You never carry more than 1 brick at any time.

Comment: The first example does not have any loop, so it reads and outputs one character. The second example has a loop, so it reads and outputs until the end condition is met. Note that input is buffered, so you didn't get *any* output until you pressed Enter.

Comment: It is a remarkable coincidence to see this question entered 13 hours after [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68292096/i-am-reading-the-c-programming-language-2ed-and-i-didnt-understand-a-concep/68292374#68292374).

Comment: @PradakshPrarthan don't put code in comments, it's unreadable. But [edit] the question.

Comment: Please can somebody check the new edited question..

Comment: Your _assumption how program might be working_ is right. _Why d = getchar(); collects character from buffer. Why it does not just start a new stream for itself...?_ The C standard demands that: __The `getchar` function returns the next character from the input stream pointed to by `stdin`.__ _I mean c = getchar(); says ok start typing
and

d = getchar(); No, don't start typing. first check if buffer has something left._ This perceived difference does not exist; the first `getchar()` does in exactly the same way _first check if buffer has something left_, it's just at the start it hasn't.

Comment: @Armali you should post your comment as an answer

Comment: That would be a good suggestion, hadn't Eric Postpischil already fired and forgot his single-handedly close weapon.

Comment: Thank you @Armali i got it now. It's clear to me now. I have one more question. Why 'int' is used and not float or char or any other declaration ? They mentioned to use int specifically, why so?? The also said -- "We must declare c to be a type big enough to hold any value that getchar returns. We can't use char since c must be big 
enough to hold EOF in addition to any possible char. Therefore we use int. "--. I didn't get the meaning of this.

Comment: If `char` has 8 bits and `EOF` the value −1, the character 0xFF and `EOF` in two's complement representation are indistinguishable after assigned to a `char`, so `char` is not _big enough_. - `float` would be a possible, but strange choice for an integer value.

Answer (score 0):

The while loop, re-executes the statements as long as the validation condition remains true.
Delayed echo output illustrates buffered input, when the entered characters are accumulated and
stored in a time domain called a buffer. Pressing a key
-Enter- makes the block of typed characters available to the program.

Answer (score -1):

Getchar will take the input in a stream and when he does it he does not delete the stream.

The thing is he get a data then you print you check the while then you go in getchar then you read the next data in the stream

try it by yourself with this

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int c;
    c = getchar();
    while(c <= 50){
        putchar(c);
        c = getchar();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and use random number you will see it will stop when he find a number with an ascii value more or equal to 51